# Weird method to check if a float number is negative

Tags: c++, c, function, floating-point, printf

In a C++ project, I saw this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

static int isNegative(float arg)
{
    char p[20]; // Assume 20 is enough
    sprintf(p, "%f", arg);
    return p[0] == '-';
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", isNegative(-1));
}
```

I heard that [`sprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) might be problematic, since it may cause the negative sign to be gone when written to `p`. Is that true? Or is that method bullet proof (but awfully bad practice)?

---

PS: Ignore the corner case of `-0`. Focus on `sprintf()`. I know that much better solutions exist, but I am just curious for this one. People from C are also welcomed to help.

Comment: _"Or is that method bullet proof"_ No, it isn't (still same as it was yesterday).

Comment: [std::signbit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit) "This function detects the sign bit of zeroes, infinities, and NaNs. Along with std::copysign, std::signbit is one of the only two portable ways to examine the sign of a NaN."

Comment: I have a strange feeling of deja vu

Comment: I remember seeing this as an example of trolling colleagues

Comment: Was it a test to reveal if the reviewers were paying attention?

Comment: Please define "negative".... what about `NaN`s? Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Negative usual number, like the score of the question @BasileStarynkevitch! =) Maybe my question pollutes SO, thus should be deleted... user0042, no it's not, look twice.

Comment: "but I am just curious for this one". It's a bit hard to ignore how terribly bad this is. A bit like: "Apart from that Mrs Lincoln, how did you enjoy the play?"

Comment: `char p[2]; snprintf(p, sizeof p, "%f", arg); return p[0] == '-';` is sufficient to handle the buffer size issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `%+f` to make sure the sign (`+` or `-`) is output (though `-` will be output regardless). So I think it is guaranteed for normal float values.

My only concern was about special values: inf and nan. So I've added printing `p` to the output and made an experiment. Here is what I've got with gcc 6.3:

```
printf("IsNegative: %d\n", isNegative(+1.0/+0.0));
printf("IsNegative: %d\n", isNegative(-1.0/+0.0));
printf("IsNegative: %d\n", isNegative(+0.0/+0.0));
printf("IsNegative: %d\n", isNegative(+0.0/-0.0));
printf("IsNegative: %d\n", isNegative(-0.0/+0.0));
printf("IsNegative: %d\n", isNegative(-0.0/-0.0));
```

Results:

```
p = +inf
IsNegative: 0
p = -inf
IsNegative: 1
p = -nan
IsNegative: 1
p = -nan
IsNegative: 1
p = -nan
IsNegative: 1
p = -nan
IsNegative: 1
```

The result only looks strange for nan, apart from that the method should work.

Comment: Sine and sign are two very different things :) But I do not understand why you bring up `%+f` at all. A `-` sign gets printed regardless, and that's the only thing that gets checked, right?

Comment: @hvd, you are right, `-` should be output regardless, I added it rather for convenience. `+` could be used if you'd like to compare `p[0]` with `+` for example.

Comment: Unfortunately, like many things in C, testing doesn't prove anything. I would not expect this to be reliable way on different systems, especially in the case of negative nan.

Comment: @user694733, agree about nan, it can be compiler/architecture/... dependent. I don't know any documentation about it. But it would be weird  if it did not work for "normal" floats.

Comment: @Mikhail the question is heavily downvoted. Do you think I should delete it? I mean it may polute SO...

Comment: @gsamaras, As you wish, I will not feel upset :) True, that the question is not extremely useful in practice, but at the same time I don't think it is completely useless.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the basic math rule that specify a negative value is lesser than 0 and positive greater than 0.

```
#include <cstdio>

static int isNegative(float arg)
{
    return ((static_cast<int>(arg+1) > 0) ? 0 :1);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", isNegative(-1));
    printf("%d\n", isNegative(-0.046));
    printf("%d\n", isNegative(3));
    printf("%d\n", isNegative(0.253));
}
```

Result:

```
1
1
0
0
```